# Reading text from website using sockets Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets

I am trying to go to http://www.py4inf.com/code/romeo.txt, read the contents of romeo.txt and print them back out, am using python 3.6.1.

```
import socket

mysock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
mysock.connect(('www.py4inf.com', 80))
mysock.send('GET http://www.py4inf.com/code/romeo.txt HTTP/1.0\n\n'.encode("utf8"))

while True:
    data = mysock.recv(512)
    if ( len(data) < 1 ) :
        break
    print (data.decode("utf8"))

mysock.close()
```

instead of the contents of the page it prints out

```
TTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Server: nginx
Date: Wed, 21 Jun 2017 03:00:15 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 162
Connection: close
 <html>
<head><title>404 Not Found</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>404 Not Found</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx</center>
</body>
</html
```

Why is this? Thanks in advance

Comment: Mac's answer solves your problem, but I would really recommend you take a look at `requests` (http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/). Makes your life so much easier.

Comment: I will take a look at this, thanks for the advice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In theory, the `Host` header is only mandatory from HTTP 1.1 onwards, but it appears that particular server requires the `Host` header to be present, even for HTTP 1.0. I'm not sure if that's the default behaviour of Nginx, or whether the server admin's explicitly configured it that way.

In any case, try changing your request to the following:

```
mysock.send('GET http://www.py4inf.com/code/romeo.txt HTTP/1.0\nHost: www.py4inf.com\n\n'.encode("utf8"))
```

I can understand your confusion - IMHO, it should be returning `400` not `404` if it is insisting on the `Host` header being provided (since it's a client request issue, not a matter of the resource not existing).